# Property of Modified Bessel function of first kind

Tags: bessel-functions

While reading a scientific paper, I have come across a property of modified Bessel function: $$\frac{I_1(az)}{I_0(az)}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{I_1(z)}{I_0(z)}$$ Is this property true? If not, how can the LHS be written in terms of $I_1(z)$ and $I_0(z)$?

Comment: You have significantly changed your question. So that the answer makes sense to future readers I recommend you revert the question and ask your follow up query as a new question.

Comment: My bet is on a continued fraction gone bad & wrong during transcription.

Comment: Perhaps the OP can provide a link to the scientific paper they were reading to give some more context.

Comment: @IanMiller: Here's the [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/thermoacoustic-wave-equations-for-gas-in-a-channel-and-a-tube-subject-to-temperature-gradient/89C4C4BAE7581F47055C0A0EFAE810BA) . But I'm not sure if you'll be able to access. You can get in on sci-hub using the doi (10.1017/S0022112010001540). Warning: the property is not given directly although it can be deduced from eq 4.13 and 4.17 of the paper

Comment: No. Its behind a subscription wall. Maybe you can quote the two equations you have mentioned.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: I do not get how your identity follows from 4.13 and 4.17. Probably you exploited some definition and a scale-property of the Fourier (inverse) transform, while the (inverse) Fourier transform used by the authors has a different normalization constant. That is a common issue, see (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html): *some authors...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is not true.

Graph from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BBesselI%5B1,%202%20x%5D%2FBesselI%5B0,%202%20x%5D,%20%20%20%201%2F2%20BesselI%5B1,%20x%5D%2FBesselI%5B0,%20x%5D%7D,%20%7Bx,%20-3,%203%7D%5D).

[image]